# Outlook Calendar Sync with custom calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar

We have our own custom calendar in our portal which is developed in Java. Is there a way to sync this calendar with Outlook calendar. I can sync this calendar with Google Calendar as Google Calendar API is available. Does anyone know any documentation or links where I can read about this?

Thanks

Comment: I think that you could solve this without any programing using Outlook-Google sync (then strictly it should not be on here) http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955 

If you need to do it programmatically can you tell us a bit more about what your java calendar and how that works ? does it have any api or db itself ?

Comment: Well our calendar is completely written in Java and has its own db to store events, alerts. That's why I said, I can integrate google calendar easily using google's api for calendar.

Comment: Set up your Java calendar to look at an google calendar that you have an outlook sync with.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have decided finally. Syncing our calendar with google and google with Outlook.

Comment: I also want to know if there is a workaround with this..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am syncing our calendar with google and google calendar with outlook.

Comment: how did you sync the calendar to google?...and then google calendar to outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use COM to interact with Office products.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sync your proprietary calendar with Google Calendar then you can sync your Google Calendar with Outlook using WebDAV.
So you could:

1. Use some Outlook plugins to access the Google Calendar using WebDAV API
2. Use the standard Outlook Publish/Subscribe functionality with some WebDAV based online syncing service (I use [Synqya](http://synqya.appspot.com)) that allows you to sync your Outlook events with Google Calendar